# CustomComponent FindViewById from referenced project returns null

Tags: xamarin.android, android-linearlayout, custom-component

In C# Xamarin Android projects, I am trying to create a custom compound component to select a month.  This extends `LinearLayout`.

I expect to re-use it (and keep my main project more tidy), so I have 2 projects - my main/parent project, containing my Activity and multiple Fragments; and a simple Android project for my component.

When I run the component project directly using its own Activity, it works as expected, but when I reference it from my main project, my `FindViewById` return `null`.

I can see that `this` and `context` are from the main project - and I would like to understand what I've done wrong or what I need to add so that it finds the component's layout and controls to inflate?

Main view (`Ui.DateScrollPicker.Droid` is my component's namespace and `ScrollMonthPicker` my class):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

  .......

  <ui.datescrollpicker.droid.ScrollMonthPicker
    android:id="@+id/my_scroll_month_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Referenced from a `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` in the `override View OnCreateView` method:

```
    scrollMonthPicker = view.FindViewById<ScrollMonthPicker>(Resource.Id.scroll_month_picker);
    scrollMonthPicker.DateChanged += DatePicker_Changed;
```

By extending `LinearLayout`, I am implementing 2 constructors, including, `ScrollMonthPicker(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs, 0)` which is called, and goes off to inflate my component's layout.

Component view (scroll_month_layout.axml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/month_current_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Month" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/year_current_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Year" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/month_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</merge>
```

ScrollMonthPicker constructor:

```
public ScrollMonthPicker(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    : base(context, attrs, 0)
{
    InflateLayout(context, attrs);
}
```

ScrollMonthPicker inflating view:

```
private void InflateLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
{
    var inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(this.Context);
    inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.scroll_month_layout, this);

    monthCurrentText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.month_current_text);
    yearCurrentText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.year_current_text);
    monthRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.month_recycler_view);
    monthRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;

    ......
}
```

The component works fine when called from 'its own' Activity, but all `FindViewById` are null (`monthCurrentText`, `yearCurrentText` and `monthRecyclerView`) when referenced by the fragment in the main project.

If I wait for the exception to be thrown in the main fragment from `monthRecyclerView.HasFixedSize`, I do not get a null reference exception, but this one:

```
Unhandled Exception:

    System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0x7fff30d40b00 (key_handle 0x8f4c53e) of Java type 'md53fd9f663a5e8ddcd0a5da1b57d05fd99/ScrollMonthPicker' as managed type 'Ui.DateScrollPicker.Droid.ScrollMonthPicker'.
```

How do I make it populate as expected by referencing from a separate project??

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you both project are the android project? You could not use another android project code in one project. I think you need to create your 
CustomComponent project as a library.

Comment: Hi @Billy, many thanks for your comment - that has fixed it, and I'm pretty pleased! :o)  Seems obvious now...  If you wanted to add it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your both projects are the android project. You could not use another android project code in one project. I think you need to create your CustomComponent project as a library.